# Is it possible to find all classes annotated with @MyAnnotation using a GWT GeneratorContext?

Tags: gwt

While creating classes using [Generators](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred#generators), it's possible to discover all subclasses of a type. You can find this technique for example in the GWT Showcase source (see [full code](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.4/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/generator/ShowcaseGenerator.java#94)):

```java
JClassType cwType = null;
try {
  cwType = context.getTypeOracle().getType(ContentWidget.class.getName());
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
  logger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "Cannot find ContentWidget class", e);
  throw new UnableToCompleteException();
}
JClassType[] types = cwType.getSubtypes();
```

I would like to do something similar, but instead of *extending* a class (or implementing an interface)

```java
public class SomeWidget extends ContentWidget { ... }
```

, could I also do this by *annotating* Widgets?

```java
@MyAnnotation(...)
public class SomeWidget extends Widget { ... }
```

And then finding all Widgets that are annotated with @MyAnnotation? I couldn't find a method like `JAnnotationType.getAnnotatedTypes()`, but maybe I'm just blind?

<sub>Note: I was able to make it work with the [Google Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library, using `reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(SomeAnnotation.class)`, but I'd prefer using the GeneratorContext instead, especially because this works a lot better when reloading the app in DevMode.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - easiest way is to iterate through all types, and check them for the annotation. You might have other rules too (is public, is non-abstract) that should also be done at that time.

```
for (JClassType type : oracle.getTypes()) {
  MyAnnotation annotation = type.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
  if (annotation != null && ...) {
    // handle this type
  }
}
```

The `TypeOracle` instance can be obtained from the `GeneratorContext` using `context.getTypeOracle()`.

Note that this will only give you access to types on the source path. That is, only types currently available based on the modules being inherited and `<source>` tags in use.

Comment: +1, that definitely works, and I didn't consider this approach. It's kind of a brute-force way (which doesn't matter too much since no one will have millions of types). I will gladly accept your answer, if there is no pre-defined solution for this.

Comment: It feels brute force from the perspective of most Java, but within just the source path it won't be so bad. Plus, that is what the function in the Google Reflections library is going to have to do as well - find and look at all classes currently on the classpath.